# Update column value in Cassandra table if value exists

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra table as below

```
CREATE TABLE inventory(
    prodid varchar,
    loc varchar,
    qty float,
    PRIMARY KEY (prodid)
) ;
```

Requirement :

For the provided primary key, if no record exists in table, we need to insert, which is straight forward. but when the record exists for the primary key, then we need to update the qty column by adding the existing value in the table with new values received.

As per my understanding,  I need to query the table first  for the provided primary key and get the value of the qty  column and add  with new value received from the request and execute the update query with light weight transaction.

Ex: table has say qty 10 for the prodid=1 and if I receive from user new qty as 2 (which is delta), then I need to update qty as 12 for the prodid=1.

Is that logic is correct? or any better way to design the table or handle the use case? Will this approach introduce latency issue during the load as we need to do select query first and if data exists update the column value with new value ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the qty column to static. This way you do not have to update the table but Insert. Updates are resource intensive so cassandra treats UPDATE statement as insert statement. So, your table definition should be -

```
CREATE TABLE inventory( 
prodid varchar, 
loc varchar, 
qty float static, 
PRIMARY KEY (prodid) ) ;
```

So you can use your business logic to calculate the new value of QTY column and use INSERT statement, which intern update the same column.

Other way is to use counter column -

```
CREATE TABLE inventory( 
prodid varchar, 
loc varchar, 
qty counter, 
PRIMARY KEY (prodid, loc ) ) ;
```

Which this design you can just use update query like  below -

```
update inventory set qty = qty + <calculated Quantity> where prodid = 1;
```

Notice that, in second table design, all other columns have to the part of primary key. In your case, it is easy and convenient.

Comment: qty is not a auto increment column, it is a quantity which we receive from upstream, so i need to update value I receive from upstream, if the record already exists for the specific prodid column.

Comment: update inventory set qty = qty + <calculated Quantity> where prodid = 1;

Comment: If I tried to update with  following statement,    update inventory set qty=qty+500 where prodid=33237;  I see error - InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid operation (qty = qty + 500) for non counter column qty". So this means it is not applicable for normal columns other than counter column

Comment: You need to change the table definition,  the column QTY is of type COUNTER